# How to embed arbitrary expressions as-is into another place in R?

Tags: r, shiny, metaprogramming

#### Context

I need to use R metaprogramming for use with the framework Shiny, as their modules and event handlers depend on metaprogramming for passing expressions and executing it in the right context for evaluation to chain with pre-defined input, output, and session objects.

To simplify the problem, I'm going to use the example of a `source()` function.

#### Example

To run Shiny, Shiny requires two objects: `ui` and `server`. The `server` is a function: `server <- function(input, output, session)`.

All I want to do is this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   source('fileA.R', local=TRUE)
   source('fileB.R', local=TRUE)
}
```

This works on its own. However, I have about ten different files to include. So I created a function to return the required code to execute within it:

```
run_server <- function(str) {
  names <- strsplit(x=str, split='/')
  code <- character()
  
  for (i in 1:length(names)) {
    module_names <- ''
    filenames <- ''
    
    module_names[i] <- names[[i]][length(names[[i]])]
    filenames[i] <- paste0(str[i], '/server_', module_names[i], '.R')
    code <- paste0(code, "source(\'", filenames[i], "\'", ", local = TRUE)", "\n")
  }
  
  return(parse(text=code))
}
```

This works fine... except that it returns the type `expression` from R, which is different than the return type of `quote` or `substitute`. It also means that if I try to use `eval/evalq` on this, it doesn't work the way I expect.

I've resorted to trying to create the server function using another helper function:

```
make_server <- function(...) {
  code <- eval(substitute(...))
  func <- bquote(function(input, output, session) {
    .(code)
  })

  
  return(
    func
  )
}
```

But once again, the function body is a bit weird--it still has the `expression()` function wrapped around the contents of its body:

```
function(input, output, session) {
    expression(source("modules/upload_rds/server_upload_rds.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/download_rds/server_download_rds.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/fileupload/server_fileupload.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/normalization/server_normalization.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/outlier_zmedian/server_outlier_zmedian.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/basic_nmf/server_basic_nmf.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/monocle/server_monocle.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/deseq2/server_deseq2.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/fem_analysis/server_fem_analysis.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/topGO/server_topGO.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/cluster_profiler/server_cluster_profiler.R", 
        local = TRUE), source("modules/scde/server_scde.R", local = TRUE), 
        source("modules/edgeR/server_edgeR.R", local = TRUE))
}
```

And this doesn't evaluate as if the code was simply copy-pasted or truly substituted like a C preprocessor would.

#### `expression()` vs. `quote()`

Reading this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531615/difference-between-quote-and-expression-in-r), it appears that an expression is a vector of calls, etc. So the natural thing to do would be to just apply something like `unlist()` or `c()`. But this doesn't work. Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: why don't you just write a pkg to contain the "modules"?

Comment: @hrbrmstr That's not the core problem here, though. The problem is the substitution and evaluation of code doesn't work the way I expect. And, if anything, I didn't know enough about package development when I started the project. I decided to forgo it.